# CPU overload spam - redirect link to wp-admin and new post

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, login, urls, spam

I noticed my wordpress website is over utilizing CPU resources causing my shared hosting to trottle slowing down drastically my website.

Upon doing a CPanel inspection on resources, I found this strange link utilizing quite a lot of CPU

```
mydomain.com/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost-new.php
```

Can anyone tell me what is this and how to solve this or troubleshoot this case ?

Comment: It could well be an automated bot attack - such traffic is not particularly unusual in the web world, sadly. Normally it shouldn't consume much in the way of server resources unless it's a sustained brute-force attack. You might look into security solutions such as those provided by WordFence and the Cloudflare services to handle automatically banning IPs for repeat offenses and throttle potentially malicious traffic and the like.

Comment: well, cloudflare "under attack mode" seems to stop most of it. just curious if this is any backdoor passage to wordpress

Comment: It looks to me like they're just hammering the login and telling WordPress to immediately redirect them to the new post screen, which would be necessary to acquire NONCEs to submit new content. As long as you haven't noticed any new content (might be worth a peek at the DB to confirm), it seems the security is holding :) . No backdoor - just a lot of knocking at the front.